# USB install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS for dual boot with Win10 --> blackscreen issue

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, usb, uefi

> !! New edit / information at the bottom !!
>
> Please help me fix the "FAILED" message

First: I know that there are a lot of questions about the same topic, however, I searched the forum and tried different solutions, but nothing worked for me so far.

**Problem:**

I'm desperately trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 via a Live CD (USB) as a dual boot on my machine, but no matter what I try I run into a black screen after choosing "Try Ubuntu without installing" or "Installing Ubuntu" in the boot menu. Please help me fix this issue :-)

**Error Message:**

The problem is that I don't even get any error messages at all. I can enter the boot menu and select my USB-stick just fine. Then I'm in the screen where I can choose what to do, for instance "try out Ubuntu live", "install ubuntu", "etc", and I can also change the boot parameter. When I try the "try-out" option or the "install option" I get a pink Ubuntu loading screen for a few moments, followed by a black-screen. At the black-screen state I can't do anything anymore and have to hard-restart my computer.

**What I already tried:**

1. I tried several USB sticks and several programs to create a Live USB stick (for instance: Rufus, Universal USB Installer, ...). Moreover, I tested the USB sticks on different machines, and there they worked just fine.
2. I changed the boot parameter from "quite splash" to "nomodeset", "acpi=off" and "nolapic". Nothing worked so far.
3. I tried using "UEFI" boot mode, as well as "UEFI + Legacy" boot mode. --> Nothing changed.
4. I tried USB2 ports, as well as USB3 ports. --> No luck
5. I tried connecting to my monitor with a Display Port, Mini Display Port and HDMI cable. --> No luck [No DVI/VGA connection available]

**Setup:**

I have 3 drives: C:\ --> NVMe SSD, D:\ --> SSD, E:\ --> HDD.

On the C-drive I have Windows 10 installed, and I would like to install Ubuntu on the free partition on my SSD (D-drive). I already resized and freed space on the partition:

[image: Picture-Filesystem-Manager]

**System Specs:**

- Motherboard: X99A SLI PLUS(MS-7885)
- Chipset: Intel X99
- BIOS: 1.D0 (up-to-date version, flashed already)
- Boot mode: UEFI (also tested in UEFI + Legacy, but same error)
- Fast Boot: disabled
- Secure Boot: disabled
- Monitor: ROG PG279Q [only HDMI or Display Port connection, 1440p]
- GPU: GTX 1080, up-to-date driver installed
- NO integrated onboard graphics on motherboard (!)
- CPU: i7-5820K (overclocking disabled for the installation)

**Others:**

For performance and stability reasons a "Wubi install" of Ubuntu is not possible for me.

.

**Edit - 1:**

So, I finally manged to get more information out of the system. I grew frustrated and tried to install Ubuntu with literally all boot parameters set in legacy mode, and got some new error messages:

**What I did:**

1. Switched to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS from Ubuntu 16.04.1
2. Changed my boot-options to Legacy mode (even so Windows is in UEFI mode)
3. Tried "Install Ubuntu" with the parameter: "acpi=off", "noapic", "nolapic", "edd=onn", "nodmraid", "nomodeset"
4. Got "Failed" messages, see below
5. Got black-screen after encountering the "Failed" messages

**Screen Printout:**

Sorry for the blurred images, I took the photos against direct sunlight and had to overlay them with a filter to make them readable:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

-->  Then: Blackscreen

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to let you know that I fixed the problem :D :D :D.

**Short Version:**

I believe that my anti virus program (Avira Free Edition) or Windows Defender messed up the process to create a bootable USB stick. However, if the error really originated from these factors is solely a guess (~ 50% confidence).

**Longer Version:**

I tried one more time with Ubuntu 16.04.2 x64 LTS, and while using UNetBootin to get a boot'able USB-stick I noticed that Windows Defender always complained about something strange. So I disabled my anti-virus program, and I disabled Windows Defender, to then create the USB stick using UNetBootin.  --> And afterwards, the booting process worked just fine (in Legacy mode), even without adding extra boot-parameter !

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. But it is somewhat inconvenient to turn off the security tools. I suggest that you try the cloning tool Win32 Disk Imager if there is a next time from Windows, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb. Otherwise, from Ubuntu, I suggest that you use mkusb, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb